# How to open popup window with window.open() having the confirmation message as Yex/No?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, popup, window

I am opening a pop-up window having the Message asking for confirmation that "Do you want to delete a record" with Yes/No buttons. But, its not working correctly. Below is the code:

```
var modal = window.open (sUrl,"", "dialogHeight:" + iHeight + "px; dialogWidth:" + iWidth + "px;status=no;scrollbars=yes;resizable=no;titlebar=no;", null);
 modal.dialogArguments = messageObject;
```

As the program goes to this line it opens the pop-up window but does not load it and proceeds further finishing the whole JavaScript code. I want the program to stop till it gets confirmation from the child window Yes/No.

**Note:** I am getting the value of Yes/No using a hidden variable in the parent window. Here is the code written in child window and which gets me the confirmation value:

```
window.opener.setMsgValue(returnValue);
```

This is the function written in the parent window:

```
function setMsgValue(msgSel) {
            document.getElementById('msgSel').value = msgSel;
}
```

I know I can do this using the `window.showModelessDialog`. But, this works only in IE8 and I am doing this code for chrome 39.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like

```
if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
// Delete it!
} else {
// Do nothing!
}
```

It's shorter, but every browser styles it different.

Comment: Thanks for Your Answer. But, the problem is the existing application working in IE has customized Confirmation box which cant match with the chrome if i use the confirm code. I want to open the new window such that the parent window should stop execution till it gets the confirmation from the child/New window.